# badge progress stats for flagged posts

Tags: feature-request, support, badges, flag-history

For Flagging there are 3 badges available,

1. First flagged post - `Citizen Patrol`
2. Raised 80 helpful flags  - `Deputy`
3. Raised 500 helpful flags  - `Marshal`

We have Badge progress for reviewed task as following image ? From this image we can see if I review 560 more than I will be awarded with `Steward` badge.

Can we have stats to flagged-summary as it to encourage people to flag posts ?

[image]

Comment: Do we want to encourage people to flag posts? We want to encourage people to flag posts _well_. Will a badge progress thingymajig help with that?

Comment: @Ben To get clear idea how far from badge is main aspect, something like as shown in image in question. Also badge is kind of motivation factor (indirect) like appreciation in our field. Anyways it was just an idea never mind if you doesn't feel helping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I neither agree nor disagree about this, I can see the difference between those groups of badges.

Review actions are handed to us on a golden plate in a very friendly and effective manner. Just click a link and start reviewing. So having this, live progress is essential so you can see how much is left until you can "rest". :)

Flagging posts is different. We don't have any friendly mechanism giving us posts to flag; this is something that is done after you arrive to a certain post somehow and see something wrong about it.

Having summary for the flagging badges is just something "nice to have", but in my opinion if such thing is implemented then badge progress for ALL other relevant badges should also be implemented, and I doubt such thing will happen.

Answer (score 4):

It is available in [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/696134/jennis) (under profile views)

Click on that numbers.

[image]

(Click on image to see larger image.)

Comment: [meta-tag:flagging-summary] page doesn't display anything like [badge progress](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WUvny.png "similar to as shown at OP example screen shot"). As of now, it shows only total counts and details of flags

Comment: @gnat: Yes. But by that helpful flags counts we can calculate how far we are from particular badge. For e.g. if my helpful flags are 313, I can easily understand that I am 187 (500-313) flags away from Marshal badge.

Comment: @hims056 I know about these count but I asked about badges progress. This is not the answer I am looking for.